# Calculating the ratio of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe with four columns:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
```

Desired output:

```
x1/x2  x1/x2  x1/x3  x2/x3  x2/x4  x3/x4
```

I want to create new columns which are ratios of the original columns.

Only way I could think of is to do manually:

```
df['x1/x2'] = df['x1']/df['x2']
```

However, I am going to have over 20 columns in the original data frame. Is there any way to automate this process? I am thinking for loop but I don't know where to start.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Create all pairs combinations of columns names, loop and divide to new columns:

```
from  itertools import combinations

for a, b in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    df[f'{a}/{b}'] = df[a].div(df[b])
```

Or use list comprehension, join together by `concat` and add original columns by `join`:

```
df = df.join(pd.concat([df[a].div(df[b]).rename(f'{a}/{b}') 
                         for a, b in combinations(df.columns, 2)], 1))
```

---

```
print (df)
   x1  x2  x3  x4     x1/x2     x1/x3     x1/x4     x2/x3     x2/x4     x3/x4
0   4   7   1   5  0.571429  4.000000  0.800000  7.000000  1.400000  0.200000
1   5   8   3   3  0.625000  1.666667  1.666667  2.666667  2.666667  1.000000
2   4   9   5   6  0.444444  0.800000  0.666667  1.800000  1.500000  0.833333
3   5   4   7   9  1.250000  0.714286  0.555556  0.571429  0.444444  0.777778
4   5   2   1   2  2.500000  5.000000  2.500000  2.000000  1.000000  0.500000
5   4   3   0   4  1.333333       inf  1.000000       inf  0.750000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'x2': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'x3' : [100, 100, 100 ,100, 100], 'x4': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})

columns = df.columns

def pattern(c = columns):
    yield from ((v1, v2) for i, v1 in enumerate(c) for v2 in c[i + 1:])

for name1, name2 in pattern():
    df[f'{name1}/{name2}'] = df[name1].div(df[name2])
```

output:

[image]

also, you can concatenate all your desired columns:

```
pd.concat([df[n1].div(df[n2]).rename(f'{n1}/{n2}') for n1, n2 in pattern()], 1)
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do a oneliner with assign:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df = df.assign(**{f'{a}/{b}': df[a]/df[b] for a,b in combinations(df,2)})
```